# Why doesn't this simple destroy method expectation work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, destroy

After doing some research here, and using Google I'm still confused as to why this simple spec isn't working:

```
describe CartsController do
  #stuff omitted...
  describe "carts#destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested cart" do
      cart = FactoryGirl.create(:cart)
      puts "Cart count = #{Cart.count}"
      expect {
        delete :destroy, :id => cart.id
      }.to change(Cart, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
#stuff omitted...
end
```

Here's the CartsController's action:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @cart = current_cart
    @cart.destroy
    session[:cart_id] = nil

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(store_url, :notice => 'Your cart is currently empty') }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end

end
```

And last but not least, **the error** I'm getting:

```
Cart count = 1
F

Failures:

  1) CartsController carts#destroy destroys the requested cart
     Failure/Error: expect {
       count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/carts_controller_spec.rb:146:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 6.68 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

I'm new to rspec tests, however, As far as I understand my destroy spec is very straightforward, and it should perform as expected. I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong..

Please help me,
Thankful as always,

EDIT.. here's the current_cart method:

```
def current_cart
  Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you provide, I guess you should simply add:

```
session[:cart_id] = cart.id
```

before your `expect` block.

Why? It seems you're not really using the id passed in the url but the value stored in session. But to be sure, you should provide your `current_cart` method.

Comment: I've added the current_cart method, 
Anyways, at this point maybe irrelevant because your solution works! You're a wizard man !

Comment: yep, as assumed, you don't rely on the id you pass in the url but only on the session. So my answer fits :)

Comment: I have a very important question if you don't mind, How can I simulate (or stub or mock) the call to current_cart done inside the destroy method?
I think that would be even better and more understandable than just storing the cart id in session[:cart_id] right?

Comment: yep, you could do: `Cart.should_receive(:find).and_return(cart)` instead of setting the session

Comment: right. But is there a way at all to place the name current_cart inside the test somehow (stub/mock-wise)? I thought about doing it the way you described btw, never thought the test COULD GO as deep as that.. ;)

Comment: mmm, not sure but try: `controller.stub(:current_cart).and_return(cart)`

Comment: Awesome! That worked very well sir. Thank you! 
I have one more little question: Where should I put any of your last two suggestions: outside & before the expect block, or inside the expect block? (they both work.)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you are destroying `current_cart` which might be getting created inside the expectation in the spec, and then destroyed, leading to a change of 0. Check how `current_cart` is being created/used.

Comment: Yep, it was all about the current_cart method, sir
Thank you!